# Android handeling swipe gesture on an edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, gesture, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to get a swipe gesture to work on an EditText.
However everything I try tends to be buggy.

When I return false the gesture works but the cursor moves when making a swipe gesture.
However when I return the result from the GestureListener (onFling) the cursor stay's in place, but on Android 2.3.3 after the gesture is finished the context menu from the text edit pops up, on 4.1.2 there is no context menu, but making the gesture will select a whole word.

Here is my current code:

```
package com.example.testmarkup;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    public interface OnSwipeListener {
        public void OnSwipe();
    }

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector = null;

    private OnSwipeListener mOnSwipeLeftListener;

    private OnSwipeListener mOnSwipeRightListener;
    private GestureListener mGestureListener = null;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(final Context context) {
        mGestureListener = new GestureListener();
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, mGestureListener);      
    }

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        final boolean result = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        //When I return false here the gesture works but the cursor moves when making a swipe gesture.
        //However when I return the result from the GestureListener (onFling) the cursor stay's in place,
        //but on Android 2.3.3 after the gesture is finished the context menu from the text edit pops up,
        //on 4.1.2 there is no context menu, but making the gesture will select a whole word.
//      return false;  
        return result; 

    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                final float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                final float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                            result = true;
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                            result = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                            result = true;
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                            result = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (final Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
        if (mOnSwipeRightListener != null)
            mOnSwipeRightListener.OnSwipe();
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        if (mOnSwipeLeftListener != null)
            mOnSwipeLeftListener.OnSwipe();
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }

    public OnSwipeTouchListener setOnSwipeLeft(final OnSwipeListener aListener) {
        mOnSwipeLeftListener = aListener;
        return this;
    }

    public OnSwipeTouchListener setOnSwipeRight(final OnSwipeListener aListener) {
        mOnSwipeRightListener = aListener;
        return this;
    }    

}
```